# Mapping File information (Set of Strings) to POJO(s)

Tags: spring-boot, type-conversion

Writing a spring boot application where I'm reading certain .pgn files.

Having a .pgn file contains information about games. Example content of one specific file may be of 2 games like:

--------------------------

```
[Event "Paris Open"]
[Date "2023.04.07"] 
[White "Smith, Mike"]
[Black "Taylor, Leo"]
[Result "1-0"]

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nc3 d5 4. Nf3 c5 5. cxd5 cxd4 1-0

[Event "Paris Open"]
[Date "2023.04.07"]
[White "Lopez, Maria"]
[Black "Jones, John"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nc3 Nc6 3. Nf3 Nf6 1/2-1/2
```

--------------------------

MappingJacksonValue handles JSONs
and JAXB Marshaller handles XML...but how would we do it in the "general" case, like the above format, is my question.

1.
How would i convert this into POJOs in the simplest way?

2.
How would i convert the POJOs back to the original format (meaning a String I suppose)?